# Getters and setters for constants?

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, constants, getter

Is is possible to create getters and setters for constants? I want to refer to a constant directly, and have it instantiate itself if it's value is nil. A constant declared like this:

```
// Prefs.h
extern MyClass * const kThing;

// Prefs.m
MyClass * const kThing = nil;
```

and the getter/setter would look like:

```
// getter
+ (MyClass *)kThing
{
    _kThing = _kThing ? : [MyClass new];
    return _kThing;
}

// setter
+ (void)setKThing:(MyClass *)myClass
{
    _kThing = myClass
}
```

And then I could use it like:

```
[kThing doSomething];
```

Is this possible?

**edit** edited the methods to class methods

Comment: Are you declaring `kThing` as a global variable? If so, why are the getter and setter instance methods?

Comment: @drewmm Yes, I want it to be a global constant. I changed it to class methods to make it more clear. Although I'm not sure which class those are supposed to be members of...I was just using it as an example.

Comment: Time to lookup the word constant.. ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global variable declaration in other file is very dangerous in objective C. Ideally we use  sharedInstance. Try like this:

In MyGame.h

```
@interface MyGame : NSObject
{
   int mScore;
}
@property(nonatomic,assign) int score;
+(MyGame*)sharedObject;
-(void)someFunction;
@end
```

In MyGame.m

```
static MyGame *gGame = nil;

@implementation MyGame

@synthesize  score = mScore;

+(MyGame*)sharedObject
{
   if(!gGame)
   {
       gGame = [[MyGame alloc] init];
   }
   return gGame;
}

-(void)someFunction
{

}
@end
```

To access anywhere in project:

```
     #import "MyGame.h"

     [MyGame sharedObject].score;
     [MyGame sharedObject] someFunction];
```

Comment: It's very dangerous to use globale anywhere.  Leads to some terrible implicit masking and double-symbols in the linker

Answer (score 2):

What you describe are not constants, they are global variables. You cannot define getters and setters for them, but you can use their values to back class methods, which is precisely what you have done.

However, when you send message like this

```
[kThing doSomething];
```

the global variable is used directly, bypassing your getter. If you want to go through a getter, you can write

```
[[MyClass kThing] doSomething];
```

or inside methods of `MyClass` you can write

```
[[[self class] kThing] doSomething];
```

Another note is that when yo implement accessor methods like that, you should make the backing variables static, rather than `extern`. This will ensure that other modules cannot access these variables bypassing your getters.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that this is not possible.

```
MyClass * const kThing = nil;
```

means that `kThing` is a constant pointer, which means that the address in memory that it points to cannot be changed. So once it's set to `nil`, it can't later be set to a new object.